# How are some college athletes several years older than the rest?

Tags: collegiate

How is it that some college athletes can be 25, 26 years old while most are the age that you would expect of people recruited out of high school? (18-22)

Comment: One example is [Brandon Weeden](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brandon_Weeden). He was drafted into the MLB and pursued a baseball career after graduating high school in 2002, but it didn't work out. Thus, enrolled in Oklahoma State in 2007 to pursue a football career, and is currently a QB for the Houston Texans.

Comment: That said, this is very broad to consider any number of possibilities as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Students are permitted to participate in college athletics at any age as long as they follow the rules.

The most relevant rule for NCAA Division I athletes is the [Five-Year Rule](https://web1.ncaa.org/LSDBi/exec/bylawSearch?bylawSearchSubmit=Get%20Selected%20Items&multiple=731&division=1):

> **Title:** 12.8.1 - Five-Year Rule.
>
> A student-athlete shall complete his or
>   her seasons of participation within five calendar years from the
>   beginning of the semester or quarter in which the student-athlete
>   first registered for a minimum full-time program of studies in a
>   collegiate institution, with time spent in the armed services, on
>   official religious missions or with recognized foreign aid services of
>   the U.S. government being excepted.  For international students,
>   service in the armed forces or on an official religious mission of the
>   student’s home country is considered equivalent to such service in the
>   United States. *(Revised:  4/2/10, 7/31/14)*

Most students follow the traditional path of high school followed by college, and so the Five-Year Rule means that their eligibility ends around age 23.

BYU frequently has athletes who complete a two-year mission in-between high school and college, and so often their roster contains older players.

Brandon Weeden, born October 14 1983, didn't register for college until 2007 (as identified in mastermind_ed's comment), so his clock didn't start until he was age 23.